# npm install issue on angular-cli project

Tags: angular, npm, angular-cli

I have angular-cli project with node modules installed that is working properly. When I pulled project to new directory i am able to to do npm install with following warnings:

```
    npm WARN deprecated angular-cli@1.0.0-beta.26: angular-cli has been renamed to @angular/cli. Please update your dependencies.
    npm WARN deprecated minimatch@2.0.10: Please update to minimatch 3.0.2 or higher to avoid a RegExp DoS issue
    npm WARN deprecated minimatch@0.2.14: Please update to minimatch 3.0.2 or higher to avoid a RegExp DoS issue    
    npm WARN deprecated graceful-fs@1.2.3: graceful-fs v3.0.0 and before will fail on node releases >= v7.0. Please update to graceful-fs@^4.0.0 as soon as possible. Use 'npm ls graceful-fs' to find it in the tree.
    npm WARN deprecated minimatch@0.3.0: Please update to minimatch 3.0.2 or higher to avoid a RegExp DoS issue
    npm WARN prefer global marked@0.3.6 should be installed with -g
    npm WARN prefer global live-server@1.2.0 should be installed with -g
    npm WARN prefer global node-gyp@3.5.0 should be installed with -g
    npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@^1.0.0 (node_modules\chokidar\node_modules\fsevents):
    npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@1.1.1: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"win32","arch":"x64"})
    npm WARN @angular/compiler-cli@2.4.9 requires a peer of @angular/compiler@2.4.9 but none was installed.
    npm WARN @angular/compiler-cli@2.4.9 requires a peer of @angular/core@2.4.9 but none was installed.
```

I am using angular 2.4.4.why is 2.4.9 mentioned in warnings? I am afraid that some dependencies are not installed. And that's why my application is not working properly on ng serve. I don;t want to update angular-cli to RC1 since it may have more issues with dependencies. What should I do?

current versions on system:

```
angular-cli: 1.0.0-beta.26
node: 6.9.4
os: win32 x64
@angular/common: 2.4.4
@angular/compiler: 2.4.4
@angular/core: 2.4.4
@angular/forms: 2.4.4
@angular/http: 2.4.4
@angular/platform-browser: 2.4.4
@angular/platform-browser-dynamic: 2.4.4
@angular/router: 3.4.4
@angular/upgrade: 2.4.4
```

Answer (score 1):

Probably npm is trying to use latest available version because of dependencies at packages.json are written like `"@angular/common": "^2.4.0"` if you use set version strict like this `"@angular/common": "2.4.0"` everything should be OK.

Answer (score 1):

Updating to the RC will make the life easy while developing. Since `ng-update` and `ng-init` are removed temporarily from the CLI you might have to manually update it. But, it's worth the time.
I assume that issue is with the version. Updating the packages will solve the issue.

Also, If you look at the console, the warnings are suggesting you install some packages globally. Also, considering about upgrading there might be breaking changes that will take a bit of time but, not much.
Since the version is beta.26 It won't take much time.

Otherwise, for now following Michael M s answer might temporarily solve the issue.

Comment: Might as well. Recent releases have been stable and haven't broken anything

Comment: @AluanHaddad Yes. And, that's pretty amazing to work on keep updating for the latest version since you get the new fixes and new features.

Comment: Yeah, after getting behind between rc-4 and rc-5 and dealing with the ensuing pain, I said never again :-). So I always update our dev branch (quasi gitflow process) within a day of a new release coming out.